# proj4.js convert projection from 82397 to 4326

Tags: openlayers, proj

how to add utm84 51n to proj4
So i see something like this

```
proj4.defs("mySphere", "+proj=longlat +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=12345 +b=12345 +units=m +no_defs");
```

i want to add

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:36251", "????");

proj4('EPSG:36251','EPSG:4326',[long,lat]);
```

i don't understand that +proj.

**EDIT**
I already found the right projection

```
   proj4.defs("EPSG:32651", "+proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I already found the right projection
```

proj4.defs("EPSG:32651", "+proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");